# Bootstrap - Menu dropdown pushing down content

Tags: html, css

The dropdown menu pushes the content down.

I have tried all the "fixes" I could find. Position relative, absolute, static. But with those, it still pushes down, although when animation ends, the content below jumps up a bit (and also the links are on left/right side).

(Is there any other menu option on Bootstrap which makes a sidebar appear?)

I have looked through every question on Stackoverflow.
Position relative to ul, absolute, static. Also put all in one div, tried Z-index.

```css
@media (min-width: 576px), (max-width: 768px) {

 .navbar {
  padding-top: 3%;
  padding-bottom: 1%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 }

 .navbar-logo img {
  width: 175px;
  height: 21px;
 }

 .navbar-toggler {
  border-style: none;
  outline: none;
 }

 #menuCollapse {
  width: 30px;
  height: 22.5px;
  outline: none;
 }

 .navbar-nav {
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Moon;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  margin-top: 10px;
 }

 .navbar-nav li {
  padding-bottom: 10px;
 }

 .navbar-nav li a {
  position: static;
 }

 .nav-link {
  color: #ff6633;
 }

 ul {
  position: absolute;
 }

 .h10 {
  font-family: Moon;
  font-weight: 500;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 6%;
  font-size: 30px;
 }

 #chainB {
  color: #58A9FF;
  font-family: Equinox;
  font-weight: 700;
 }

 .h50 {
  font-family: Equinox;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 7%;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
 }

 .getChain {
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 7%;
 }

 #getChainBtn {
  background-color: #FF6633;
  border: none;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 15px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: Moon;
  font-weight: 700;
 }

 .imageLogos {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
 }

  .imageLogos img {
   width: 30px;
   height: 35px;
   margin-top: 3%;
  }

}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light sticky-top">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <a class="navbar-logo" href="Homepage.html"><img id="Logo" src="./Logo/Logo.png"></a>

   <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" style="outline: none;">
    <img src="./Menu/menu.png" id="menuCollapse">
   </button>

   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
     <li class="nav-item active">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style= "color: #ff6633;">ABOUT US</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style= "color: #ff6633;">FEATURES</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style= "color: #ff6633;">PRICING</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style= "color: #ff6633;">CONTACT US</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style= "color: #ff6633;">LOGIN</a>
     </li>
     <li class="nav-item">
      <a class="nav-link" href="#" style= "color: #ff6633;" >SIGN UP</a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </nav>

 <div class="content">
 <div class="h10">
  Privacy, security <br /> and freedom by the <span id="chainB">CHAIN.</span>
 </div>

 <div class="h50">
  Completely decentralized, P2P, Swift VPN built on Blockchain
 </div>

 <div class="getChain">
  <button type="button" id="getChainBtn">
   Get ChainVPN Now!
  </button>

  <div class="imageLogos">
   <img src="./Platforms/Windows.png" alt="Windows" style="margin-right: 20px;">
   <img src="./Platforms/Apple.png" alt="Apple" style="margin-right: 20px;">
   <img src="./Platforms/Android.png" alt="Android" style="margin-right: 20px;">
   <img src="./Platforms/Linux.png" alt="Linux" id="Linux">
  </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Add a JSFiddle or a Codepen link, please. It’ll be easier for someone reading this to debug.

Comment: It would be better if you add u r expected output image.

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BXQabj

Comment: The design is for mobiles (not desktops).

Comment: do u want to display about us, features,pricing on left side in mobile view?

Comment: Right now, it just pushes the content down.

Comment: I think it would be better if some menu popped up from the right side (full white screen) or maybe something that covers half of it. But that's our my skillzone :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example if you give any position to .navbar, it is just overriden with default bootstrap css styles, but you can do something like this:

```
.navbar {
        padding-top: 3%;
        padding-bottom: 1%;
        display: flex;
        justify-content: center;

        position: absolute !important; //now position is not overriden
        top: 0; 
        width: 100%;
        background-color: #fff; //just for dropdown to be visible
    }
```

And now navigation will not push content down. [Check please my example on codepen](https://codepen.io/nat-davydova/pen/wVoBQP).

Comment: That worked. I also added margin to the content below. Quick question: Do you have any idea how I can make it come from right side, like a white box that appears?

Comment: @Robust you need an off-canvas navigation, check this official bootstrap example - https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/examples/offcanvas/

Comment: @Robust if my answer works for you could you please mark it as a correct one? =)